# Unable to locate package ng-common

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

> Unable to locate package `ng-common` in Ubuntu 16.04

this is the error that i get when i am running `ng-serve`on my Visual Studio Code application.

scenario -

I was running `ng serve`
Then i got the error

> The program 'ng' is currently not installed. You can install it by
>   typing:   sudo apt install ng-common   You will have to enable the
>   component called 'universe'

So i ran this command  `sudo apt install ng-common`

And then i got the error

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
>   information... Done E: Unable to locate package ng-common

What to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing angular cli globaly with sudo user

```
sudo npm install -g angular-cli
```