# How to fix the error " Unable to locate package ng-common " in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to install an angular 7 version in my Ubuntu 16.04 system. while installing I am getting the error like this "Unable to locate package ng-common".

I tried some command line like "sudo npm install -g angular-cli", but if I use this I am getting a new error "module error".

if any other way or command line available to fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to locate package ng-common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50855572/unable-to-locate-package-ng-common)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install angular, you just need:

1. Install NPM. You can follow the steps [here](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/85484771375/how-to-install-npm).
2. Install angular-cli using NPM. `npm install -g angular-cli`. Linux users will want to run this command with sudo.
3. Create a new Angular 2 project. `ng new PROJECT_NAME`. (This will probably take a few minutes).

See: https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2016/12/12/installing-angular-2-and-other-dependencies/

Comment: Actually i already installed NPM also...some times it showed the error  "The program 'ng' is currently not installed" .but i tried most of the commands...

Comment: @SankarS, try this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7735#issuecomment-345546822